# how to check if stop streaming from kafka topic by a limited time duration or record count?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks

My ultimate goal is to see if a kafka topic is running and if the data in it is good, otherwise fail / throw an error

if I could pull just 100 messages, or pull for just 60 seconds I think I could accomplish what i wanted.  But all the streaming examples / questions I have found online have no intention of shutting down the streaming connection.

Here is the best working code I have so far, that pulls data and displays it, but it keeps trying to pull for more data, and if I try to access it in the next line, it hasnt had a chance to pull the data yet.  I assume I need some sort of call back.  has anyone done something similar? is this the best way of going about this?

I am using databricks notebooks to run my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, split}
val kafka = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafka server>:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "<topic>")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()

  val df = kafka.select(explode(split($"value".cast("string"), "\\s+")).as("word"))

  display(df.select($"word"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is you don't need streaming at all. Kafka source supports batch queries, if you replace `readStream` with `read` and adjust `startingOffsets` and `endingOffsets`.

```scala
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  ... // Remaining options
  .load()
```

You can find examples in the [Kafka streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries).

For streaming queries you can use [`once` `trigger`](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html), although it might not be the best choice in this case:

```scala
df.writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.Once)
  ... // Handle the output, for example with foreach sink (?)
```

You could also use standard Kafka client to fetch some data without starting `SparkSession`.